# Could you create a tag for the Gauss statistical software

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I would like to create a tag for the Gauss statistical software.

As an example, it would apply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802256/gauss-to-r-code-conversion). And there might be others.

The only issue I foresee is that the name could be confused with the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I understand the impulse to name things after Gauss, but people really have to think about searchability when naming programming languages.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Some big companies named their language `C#` (even though symbols are a pain to search) and `Go` (what is less generic than "go"?). I think that to succeed, a programming language SHOULD be non-searchable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went ahead and created the [gauss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gauss) tag, and added a quick tag summary. Please feel free to suggest a wiki summary (without copying from the GAUSS Wikipedia page, please), including links to any resources that you think would be helpful.

Comment: People *will* be using this tag for any of the hundred other things named after Carl Friedrich Gauss.

Comment: @5gon12eder Almost certainly, but given that the tag hadn't been created before, I don't think it will be used so much that it will be impossible to keep clean.

Comment: so why not `gauss-language`?

Comment: @DanielMahler Because we almost never put `-language` at the end of a tag, and `gauss` wasn't taken.